# How can I fit a embedded video to the parent div? (Like letterboxd posters)

Tags: html, css

I have a video and some caption for it. I would like to know how can I acomplish a similar look to the one Letterboxd.com uses for their movie posters.

Here's what I mean:

[image: Letterboxd.com poster css]

Instead of the image I want to fit an embedded video and the caption instead of the username.

Here's my code so far.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(44, 54, 65);
}

div#title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #abc;
}

div#container {
  align-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #9cf;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F1ECE4;
  width: 560;
}

div#movie-information {
  padding: 1px;
  margin: -10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #abc;
  background-color: #567;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: inherit;
  border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;
}

div#trailer-container {
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
index.html

<html>

<head>
  <title>Random Movie Trailer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="title">
    <h1>Random Movie Trailer</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="trailer-container">
      <div>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xG1hum1c4r8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="movie-information">
      <h1>Norman (Norman: The Moderate Rise and Tragic Fall of a New York Fixer)</h1>
      <p>
        <div id="scores">Critics Score: 89% Users Score: 58%
        </div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to write anything?

Comment: I'll add my code so far to the question...

Answer (score 0):

You mostly had to get rid of the padding, and let the iframe fill 100% width and height of the frame as it is displayed here:

https://jsfiddle.net/uct6hf5q/2/

```
#trailer-container {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#trailer-container div iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

I also added border radius to the container so the iframe does not overlap with the border.